# How to fit image inside box

Tags: graphics, width

I know that I can scale an image to text width with `\textwidth`, however, the template I am using requires a surrounding box and my image gets out of it.

I am using:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{blabla.jpg}
\caption{\csentence{Awesome Image} Indeed.}
\end{figure}
```

But the result is disappointing:
[image]

Comment: mmm and if you write `0.9\textwidth` instead `\textwidth` ???

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a *full* minimal working example [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Is easier for us in this way can help you copiyng and running code instead watch a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
\fbox{%
  \includegraphics[width=\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep]{blabla.jpg}%
}
```

Comment: Just in case the `\fbox` isn't contained inside a `figure` environment, it's probably a good idea to state `\noindent` before `\fbox{...}`.